# Pure JavaScript Append Text to File

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to append text to an existing textfile using only javaScript?

Comment: Are you talking about client-side (browser) JS or server-side (Node.js) JS?

Comment: I feel like there should be a martyr badge when a dumb question is asked and you get down-voted, but it still manages to acquire a lot of views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Browser JavaScript does not have access to the local file system for security reasons.

Comment: It sort of does, but its access requires a file prompt

Answer (score 0):

It does not have "arbitrary" access to the file system but it can in fact read/write local files from, eg, the browser cache directory. If you have full access to the client machine you could take advantage of this via a background script to synchronise temporary files to specific locations on the client. There are also techniques using local HTTP server daemons or modified browsers.

Of course if you wanted a "pure" JS solution the obvious question is how such a thing could be done without turning the browser into a premier malware installation system (well, assuming the browser isn't like IE that performs this task already).

Answer (score -2):

As stated, not possible with pure JS. But it is possible if you use XMLHttprequest.
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reading2.htm

Comment: XMLHttpRequests will fail for `file://` unless you explicitly disable the most important security settings, which usually allows any website on the internet to read your files. It is possible to do so with a plugin, but the OP explicitly asked for "pure javascript" only.